# how to delete selected listview item from database

Tags: android

how to delete listview selected possition id value from database my code just only listview position value which is not equal to database value i want to delete listview selected position value from listview also from database and show   KEY_TIME value of selected item in toast how to do that??

```
          msglist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
   // setting onItemLongClickListener and passing the position to the function
          @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
        int position, long arg3) {

              DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(MsgActivity.this);


        Log.d("LOGInG VALUE", "Value: " + String.valueOf(arg3));


                      db.Delete_Contact(position);



              return true;
   }
 });


   public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String CREATE_INBOX_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INBOX + "("
+ KEY_INBOXID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_MSG + " TEXT,"+ KEY_TIME + " TEXT" + ")";
public void Delete_Contact(int id) {
//   String string =String.valueOf(id);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_INBOX, KEY_INBOXID + " =? ",  new String[] { 
       String.valueOf(id) });

            db.close();
}


    }
```

Comment: Please refer to my answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932025/how-to-delete-mesage-from-listview-and-database/21932986#21932986

Comment: thats not work what does this line  mean on ur example     String[] delete = names2.get(i);

Comment: I suppose your ListView contains some objects (let's say an ArrayList<Books> mBooksArrayList). Well this class, Book, should have an ID or some identifier, which is used in the database too. So when you will want to delete it from your list, you can obtain the Book object as you know the selected position from the listView (mBooksArrayList.get(position)). So knowing the correct object you know the ID from the database and you will have to make a query to delete something from DB with the given ID. How to create a DB: http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/24/android-database-tutorial/

Comment: And you can remove it from your ListView by removing the object from the array and calling myListVIew.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: tell me listview position id   int position   is same as database key???  if i delete any listview item using listview possition it will also remove from database whrn insert position id in delete query?

Answer (score 1):

```
  DataBaseManager  data = new DataBaseManager(context.getApplicationContext());

                 String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Cart Where id= "your id";

                    Cursor  cursor = data.selectQuery(QUERY);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
                   if (count <= 0) {

                }
             else {
                data.Delete("YOUR DATABASE NAME", "YOUR ID");
                list.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

DatabaseMangerClass

```
        public class DataBaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            // The Android's default system path of your application database.

            @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
            private static String DB_PATH = "data/data/com.Salsoft.pharmapacks/";
            private static String DB_NAME = "Cart.sqlite";
            private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
            private SQLiteDatabase myData;
            private Context myContext;

            // /data/data/com.salsoft.savingdata/db/SavingData.sqlite

            /**
             * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
             * access to the application assets and resources.
             * 
             * @param context
             */
            public DataBaseManager(Context context) {
                super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
                this.myContext = context;
                Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState()
                        .equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

                if (isSDPresent) {
                    // yes SD-card is present
                } else {
                    // Sorry
                }
            }

            /**
             * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
             * database.
             * */
            public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

                boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
                if (dbExist) {
                    // do nothing - database already exist
                } else {
                    File directory = new File(DB_PATH);
                    directory.mkdirs();
                    CopyFiles();
                }
            }

            private void CopyFiles() {
                try {
                    InputStream is = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                    File outfile = new File(DB_PATH, DB_NAME);
                    outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    outfile.createNewFile();

                    if (is == null) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
                    } else {
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
                        byte buf[] = new byte[128];
                        do {
                            int numread = is.read(buf);
                            if (numread <= 0)
                                break;
                            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
                        } while (true);

                        is.close();
                        out.close();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

            }

            /**
             * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
             * time you open the application.
             * 
             * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
             */
            private boolean checkDataBase() {

                SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

                try {
                    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

                } catch (SQLiteException e) {

                }

                if (checkDB != null) {
                    checkDB.close();
                }

                return checkDB != null ? true : false;
            }

            public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

                // Open the database
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized void close() {
                if (myDataBase != null)
                    myDataBase.close();
                super.close();
            }

            public void insert(String table, String num, ContentValues content) {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

                myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                myData.insert(table, num, content);

            }

            public void update(String tablename, ContentValues content, String productid) {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                myData.update(tablename, content, "productid = ?",
                        new String[] { productid });

            }

            public void Delete(String tablename, String productid) {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

                myData.delete(tablename, "productid = ?", new String[] { productid });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            }

            // ---retrieve records---
            public Cursor selectQuery(String query) throws SQLException {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
                Cursor mCursor = myData.rawQuery(query, null);
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
                myData.close();
                return mCursor;
            }

            // //////// For Insert And Update Data ////////
            public void insert_update(String query) throws SQLException {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                myData.execSQL(query);
                myData.close();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `DatabaseManager`:

```
public void DeleteByName(String Name){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(tableName , columnName , selectionArgs);
    db.close();

}
```